# datataskwithURL() completion block not being called. Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, completionhandler

I am trying to write a basic function to make an HTTP Get request and parse the xml data that comes back.  I already have completed the section for parsing XML from a local file, but i can't seem to get any data from the server.  I tested this code below, but the completion block does not even run, for information to be passed back from the server.  Any suggestions please.

func getDatafromURL (url: String) {

```
    guard let urlforRequest = NSURL(string: url) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: urlforRequest)

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print(response)
            print(error)
    }
    task.resume()
```

}

Comment: Looks like the `NSURLRequest` is incomplete, don't you need to set the `HTTPMethod`?

Comment: actually, was able to figure this out.  The completion block was running but I wasn't seeing the affects because I was doing my UI updating in the viewdidload method.